# iOS - UITableView refresh table properly?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have lots of data and lots of rows in my tableView.
when data changes I want to update my visible cells on the screen, I really don't want to use reloadData because it's an expensive call.

Is it possible to somehow update the visible cells only?
I tried calling : `beginUpdate` & `endUpdate` on the table, but that doesn't work all the time?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure reloadData is expensive? I'd expect it to be quite cheap, as long as you're not using variable heights. It's going to query how many sections you have in the table, how many rows in each section, and purge its cache. But cells will be reloaded on demand, which means only the visible cells should be reloaded.

Comment: If you going to refresh all the _visible_ cells then reloadData shouldn't be **that** expensive.

Comment: @StevenFisher Yes in my case it's very expensive, I have lots of calculation, such as required height of the cells, and some web calls. So I probably should have said it's expensive for my case.

Comment: Yeah, if you're doing variable height cells, it's probably very expensive. Thanks for clarifying. :)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can:

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] 
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: what happens if the user later scrolls to a cell which wasnt visible when that call was made ?  he'll see out of date info i guess ?

Comment: Cells that aren't visible aren't populated with data.  They're populated as they come on screen, through the table view's data source callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .none)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try calling 'deleteRowsAtIndexPaths', a method of UITableView, right after you delete the model from your data source. For example, if you are deleting a row in editing mode, you could write something like the code below. Note that the first line in the 'if' statement removes the object from the data source, and the second line cleans up the table:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if ( editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete ) {

         [[[[[ItemsStore sharedStore] parameterArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]  objectForKey:@"data"] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
}
```